# Select Solution with real (positive, etc) coefficients - ignoring variables

Tags: equation-solving

I often need to solve equations for numerical coefficients while preserving numerous variables (e.g. to preserve scaling relations).  Thus I end up with a set of solutions like

$$
\left\{-\frac{(0.156113\, +0.0384783 i) d^{6/13} f^{6/13} m^{16/13} r^{9/13}}{g^{9/13} L^{6/13}},
-\frac{(0.156113\, -0.0384783 i) d^{6/13} f^{6/13} m^{16/13} r^{9/13}}{g^{9/13} L^{6/13}}, [...] ,
\frac{0.160785 d^{6/13} f^{6/13} m^{16/13} r^{9/13}}{g^{9/13} L^{6/13}}\right\}
$$

where [...] is possible *lots* more, ugly solutions --- while I just want the last one (for example).

**How can I select only the solution with the type of numerical coefficient I want (e.g. Real, or real & positive, etc)?**

Solve[eq,var,**dom**] doesn't seem to work with 'inexact coefficients', and trying things like 'Select[...]' seem to have the same problem.

I've found I can brute force proper selection if I just replace every variable with unity (i.e. {Sols} /.f->1 /.d->1 /.m->1 $...$ But that realls sucks...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how do you obtain these solutions in the first place? Have you tried `NSolve` (which you can ask for real solutions)?

Comment: The exact same problem results from NSolve... it can't handle those criteria for variables.

Comment: I don't understand the need for the numerical part in your solution. Can't you just solve your equations with everything symbolic while adding an extra constraint with respect to the part that you currently have as a number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Trace to pick out the coefficients. There may be a more elegant way but this seems to work.

```
sol={(1.233-0.23I)a^(1/2) b^(3/2),(1.233-0.343I)a^(1/2) b^(3/2),   
        (234.234)a^(1/2) b^(3/2)};
coeff=Map[TraceScan[Identity,#][[1]]&,sol];
rule=Select[coeff,( Im[#]<0)&];      (* Select only negative Im coefficients *) 
Extract[sol,Position[coeff,#]&/@rule]

{{(1.233 -0.23 I) Sqrt[a] b^(3/2)},{(1.233 -0.343 I) Sqrt[a] b^(3/2)}}
```

Comment: It looks like the question asks for the solutions that contain a specific type of number. So it should return the solution, not the number.

Comment: I updated the code to return the solution.

Comment: Thanks, this works... I'm a little disappointed if its the cleanest solution Mathematica can muster

Answer (score 4):

I am sure there will be some input that will break the following method, but here is a way to use `Pick` or `Select`:

Let

```
sols = {-(((0.25` + 0.5` I) x^2 y^3)/z), ((3 + I) x^3 y)/w^2, 3 - 4 I, (5.` x^5 Sqrt[y])/z^3, 2, -2.5`, 4 x^2};
```

First, note that you can get the rules to replace variables with `1`s using

```
thrd = Thread[Variables[sols] -> 1]
(* ==>  {w -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1} *)
```

and use this in to get the "coefficients" in a single step:

```
sols /. thrd
(* ==> {-0.25 - 0.5 I, 3 + I, 3 - 4 I, 5., 2, -2.5, 4}  *)
```

Now, you can use `Select` as follows:

```
Select[sols, myConditions[#] &@(# /. thrd) &]
```

where `myConditions` is any pure function specifying your criteria.

Examples:

```
Select[sols, (Element[#, Integers]) &@(# /. thrd) &]
(*==> {2, 4 x^2} *)
Select[sols, (Element[#, Complexes] && Re[#] > 2) &@(# /. thrd) &]
(* ==> {((3 + I) x^3 y)/w^2, 3 - 4 I, (5. x^5 Sqrt[y])/z^3, 4 x^2} *)
Select[sols, (Element[#, Complexes] && Im[#] < 0) &@(# /. thrd) &]
(* ==> {-(((0.25 + 0.5 I) x^2 y^3)/z), 3 - 4 I} *)
```

Alternatively, you get the same results using `Pick` as follows:

```
Pick[sols, Element[#, Integers] & /@ (sols/.thrd)]
Pick[sols, (Element[#, Complexes] && Re[#] > 2) & /@ (sols/.thrd)]
Pick[sols, (Element[#, Complexes] && Im[#] < 0) & /@ (sols/.thrd)]
```

Comment: It looks like the question asks for the solutions that contain a specific type of number. So it should return the solution, not the number.

Comment: @Sjoerd, hope this one is not too far off the mark:)